# "Table doesn't exist in engine" after updating XAMPP on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

After updating my XAMPP installation, the table names appear on the sidebar of PHPMyAdmin but when I click on one, the message `Table doesn't exist in engine` appears. I have backups of my XAMPP folder (in Applications), but attempting to restore anything makes MySQL not launch at all... Has anyone else had this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can have table where you deleted the data files from. They will show up with `show tables` and are still present in the data dictionary. You will then get a nice error when you try to access these tables.

Check the disks for the datafiles in `mysql/data/{databasename}` and see what you have left.

In some cases the relation to the data file can be corrupted and tables can be saved. The way to rescue your data depends on the `ENGINE`. Type `SHOW CREATE TABLE {yourtablename}` to see which engine is used and try the recovery methods for that given engine. Be persistent: There are a few poorly described scenarios where recovery seems hopeless but where you can still get your data back.